# How to loop over `fitted` objects from `lm`-type models in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vectorization

My ultimate goal is to compute `zoo` (*see function `pc` below*) for any number of fitted objects such as `fit1` and `fit2` shown below.

I'm wondering, though, how to loop over `fit` objects? Specifically, if user provided, say, 2 fitted objects such as `fit1` and `fit2` (*below*), how can `zoo` be computed for each fitted object?

```
library(rstanarm) 
data(kidiq)
d <- kidiq  

fit1 <- stan_glm(kid_score ~ mom_iq,
                data = d,   
                prior = normal(0, 2.5),  
                prior_intercept = normal(0, 10),  
                prior_aux = normal(0, 10)) 

fit2 <- stan_glm(kid_score ~ mom_iq,
                data = d,   
                prior = normal(0, 2.5),  
                prior_intercept = normal(0, 10),  
                prior_aux = cauchy(0, 100))
```

Function to be vectorized or looped over `fit` objects:

```
pc <- function(fit){

      y <- rstanarm::get_y(fit)
  ypred <- rstanarm::posterior_linpred(fit, transform = TRUE)

  if(family(fit)$family == "binomial" && ncol(y) == 2) {
    trials <- rowSums(y)
    y <- y[, 1]
    ypred <- ypred %*% diag(trials)
  }
  e <- -1 * sweep(ypred, 2, y)
  var_ypred <- apply(ypred, 1, var)
  var_e <- apply(e, 1, var)
zoo <- var_ypred / (var_ypred + var_e)
return(zoo)
  }
```

Comment: Note sure I understand the problem; what doesn't work with a loop or a `lapply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply(list(fit1, fit2), pc)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
compute=function(){
  for(i in ls()){
    if(class(eval(parse(text=i)))=="lm"){
      print(paste("zoo for",i,pc(eval(parse(text=i)))))
    }
  }
}
compute()
```